# What is the if-statement "if(!string)" in C checking?

Tags: c, string, if-statement

```
int func(char* string, char from, char to)
{
   int result = 0;
   if(!string) return 0;
// ...
}
```

i don't know whether this if-statement is checking, that the given string is empty or NULL. I tried to check it but I didn't receive a clear answer.

Comment: check against NULL it is.

Comment: It's a null check, `if(!string)` is the same as `if(string == 0)` is the same as `if(string ==  NULL)`.

Comment: but i wrote if(!string) return 5; and i gave an empty string, why did the function not return 5? it returned 0.

Comment: Just to amplfy, it is NOT checking for an empty string.  A literal empty string will have an address, and therefore is not NULL

Comment: how should the given string look like to receive 5 if my return is 5 for a NULL string?

Comment: `char* string = NULL;` <-- declare and initalise a pointer to NULL. `char* string = "";` <-- declare and initialise a pointer to a string literal containing a nul character.

Comment: It would be better to think of `char* string` as a pointer to a string, than the string itself.  but you can always change your `return 0;` to a `return 5;`

Comment: @Sedem It will not return 5 as you expected. That check is precisely for string NULL check. To find whether the string is empty, I've posted ny answer below. You can do either via strlen() or just *derefernce the first char of your string and comapare it with NULL as empty strings have string[0] = '\0'.

Comment: Keep safety checks in mind with @user7375520 s answer, if you think there's a chance `string` will be null, null check it, and if you're using `strlen` make sure the string has a null terminator else your code might summon [time travelling coke addicts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Comment: @George Definitely! strlen() should only be used when the string is Null terminated. Otherwise use the second way .

Answer (score 1):

> Your code checks whether string is NULL. If so, it returns 0.
>   To check whether string is empty, you could do either of the following:

```
if (strlen(string) == 0)
{
    printf("String is empty.\n");
    return -1;
}
```

> or you can do:

```
if (*string == '\0')
{
    printf("String is empty.\n");
    return -1;
}
```

> strlen() way should only be used when the string is NULL terminated.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!string)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (string==0)
```

and so it tests whether the parameter `string` that is passed is pointing to an object. Whether that object is a string (a sequence of characters terminated with a null character) it cannot check.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit confusing as logically it say 'if not string' but instead of it meaning if this is not a string it actually means if this string doesn't exist ie if it is null.